# Can't build test C++ app with Google's protobuf

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build sample C++ protobuf application with CMake. But linker can't find some methods related to protobuf.

I use example .proto file from [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#where-to-find-the-example-code). But when linker try to build object file for protobuf generated C++ code I have a lot of errors like this:

```
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InitEmptyString()'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_'
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation, char const*)'
```

I use protobuf 2.6.1 built myself with GCC 4.8.4. Sample application is built by CMake in QTCreator with QT 5.5.1 Toolset and GCC 4.8.4. There is my CMakeList.txt

```
project(protobuf-test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/lib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread protobuf)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you built protobuf yourself, where did you install it? In the system `/usr/lib`? In the usual `/usr/local/lib`? Somewhere else?

Comment: you should paste your linker command and make sure that your protobuf lib is in the search path.

Comment: I installed _libprotobuf_ into `/usr/lib`. And I use `LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/lib)` in CMakeList.txt to add this path to linker serach path.

Comment: Adding `/usr/lib` to link_directories is pointless, it should be included automatically. Use find_file and find_libraries for protobuf and use the variables you obtain from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was in the linker search path. Linker tried to use libprotobuf from OS distributon (version 8.0.0) instead of lib built by me (version 9.0.1).